# does bioconductor/bioconductor_docker:RELEASE_X_Y install CRAN packages from a fixed snapshot?

Tags: r, docker, cran, bioconductor

###### Question

Does a container instantiated from bioconductor_docker:RELEASE_X_Y also pull CRAN packages from reproducible image (e.g. via MRAN) and if not how do I accomplish this?

###### Motivation

I'm building an image with both Bioconductor and CRAN packages and want versions of both repositories pinned to a specific date.

###### Background

The [Bioconductor docker documentation](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/docker/) mentions [rocker/rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio).

However, unlike rocker/r-ver, the above images do not seem to be pinned to any reproducible CRAN image (e.g. [MRAN in the case of rocker/r-ver](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-ver))